# Saving files in xCode and making graph

Tags: xcode, file, save

I am new to programming. Now i have been learning for a few weeks and am now making my first app. Probably not for public, just for me. At least for now. So here it goes. I want the user to be able to enter his information (for example weight or something like that) into textField and then save it, so I can later form a graph (for example of weight loss through time). Now the graph should not be that much of a problem, since there are many tutorials on that. I am more interested in how to enter information, then save it so it can be later accessed. Any help? What should I read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working with UITextFields in Objective C is pretty straightforward - you can grab the NSString from such an object using the 'text' property.  Use [plists](http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphone-tutorial-storing-and-retrieving.html) for storage locally, or [JSON](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

Answer (score 0):

Look at core data tutorials especially related to Apples' doc on “[Core Data and Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004194-SW1)”

CoreData shows how to setup objects and save them to a file or simple database. Cocoa Bindings are how to make input screens pass data to object models.

You should be able to write a program to enter weights, save them and show in a table without writing any code.